# Como instalar Numpy via PIP windows 7 64 bits

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, pip

Boa tarde como faço para instalar Numpy via pip. Baixei o Python 2.7.13 e não sei instalar via pip.

Answer (score 1):

Basta executar `pip install numpy`. Já tentou isso? se não der certo, cola a mensagem de erro.

Pra adiantar um pouco os possíveis erros:

- Caso a mensagem diga que o pip não está instalado, mas vc tem certeza que ele ja está, adicione ele às variáveis de ambiente (Botão direito em Meu computador > Propriedades > Configurações avançadas do Sistema > Variáveis de ambiente > Novo... > cola o caminho do `pip`.

No meu computador ele está localizado nesse caminho: `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

- Caso o `pip` não esteja instalado, entre no [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), baixe o arquivo `get-pip.py` e execute ele usando `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: Esta dando esse erro aqui no prompt de comando.

Este é o comando que eu dei.

C:\Users\Brunoap\Desktop\2017\facul\python\numpy
-1.13.0rc2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Ai esta dando esse erro.

numpy-1.13.0rc2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platfor
m.

Answer (score 0):

Interessante também é instalar o Python(x,y) (https://python-xy.github.io/downloads.html) quem vem com todas as bibliotecas numéricas já instaladas além de diversas outras ferramentas importantes para cálculo numérico, científico, de engenharia e estatístico.

Na página do Python(x,y) tem outras importantes definições:
http://python-xy.github.io/